# Find inverse Laplace transform of $H(s)=\frac8{s^4+4}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

How can we find the inverse Laplace transform of the function 
 $$H(s)=\frac8{s^4+4}?$$

Comment: The table or anything, it is ok.Because I cannot find the formula in the table

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$H(s)=\frac8{s^4+4}=\frac{2}{s+1+i}+\frac{2}{s+1-i}+\frac{2}{s-1+i}+\frac{2}{s-1-i}$$

The infverse Laplace transform of $H(s)$ is:

$$f(t)=2\exp(1+i)+2\exp(1-i)+2\exp(-1+i)+2\exp(-1-i)$$
$$=8\cos (t)\cosh(t)$$

Comment: What is solution for invert laplace in time domain?